# Elasticsearch document id type integer vs string : Is there any performace difference?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 2.3.1. Currently all the document ids are integer. But I have a situation where the document ids can be numeric valued or sometimes alpha-numeric string. So I need to make the field type 'string'.

So, I need to know if there is any performance difference based on the type of Id. Please help....

Comment: ES document ids are always stored as strings, even if you give an integer at indexing time.

Comment: fyi http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2014/05/choosing-fast-unique-identifier-uuid.html

Answer (score 3):

Elasticsearch will store the id as a String even if your mapping says otherwise:

```
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
```

That is my mapping, but when I do a sort on _id I get documents ordered as:

10489, 10499, 105, 10514...

i.e. in String order.

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of ES (7.14) mandates the document's `_id` to be a String. You can see it in the documentation for `org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest`. `IndexRequest` mandates the `_id` to be a String field alone. No other types are supported. Example usage of `IndexRequest` can be found here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-document-index.html

In case, the above link stops working later, here is the snippet from the link:

```
IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest("posts"); 
request.id("1"); //This is the only method available to set the document's _id.
String jsonString = "{" +
        "\"user\":\"kimchy\"," +
        "\"postDate\":\"2013-01-30\"," +
        "\"message\":\"trying out Elasticsearch\"" +
        "}";
request.source(jsonString, XContentType.JSON);
```